# Windows Media Player track skip duration

Tags: windows-8, windows-media-player

When a song is playing in WMP, on pressing the left/right arrow key, the track skips forward/backward few seconds/minutes. The skip duration seems to be dynamic and depend on the track duration.

For example, for a track of length 1 hour, a left/right press is resulting in a skip of around 5 minutes. It is lower if the track length is lesser.

Is there a way I can set it to a fixed value, for example say 5 seconds irrespective of the track length?

The version I'm using is WMP 12.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to adjust "skip forward" in Windows Media Player?](https://superuser.com/questions/1156997/how-to-adjust-skip-forward-in-windows-media-player)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oppswie! I found the answer myself. The shortcut is

> Shift + Left / Shift + Right

This will skip the track forward/backward 10 seconds. Would have loved a 5 second window though.

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows Media Player Plus!](http://bmproductions.fixnum.org/wmpplus/) plug-in allows you to define global (system-wide) shortcuts for skipping forward/backward 5, 10, and 20 seconds.