# How to adjust "skip forward" in Windows Media Player?

Tags: window, windows-media-player

How to adjust "skip forward" in Windows Media Player so that when I press the Right Arrow it will skip X seconds?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it's not possible to adjust WMP's own hotkey behavior. However, the [Windows Media Player Plus!](http://bmproductions.fixnum.org/wmpplus/) plug-in allows you to define global (system-wide) hotkeys for skipping forward 5, 10, and 20 seconds.